# java regex help

Tags: java, regex

I can have one string with the following two formats:

```
"[HardCOdeText1 (HardCodeText2)].[HardCodeText3].[MatchString] between changeValue1 and changeValue2";
"[MatchString] between changeValue1 and changeValue2";
```

I would like to match if the string have `"[MatchString] between"` expression.
ANd depending upon which string I match, The changed value format should be one of the following:
The changed format should be :

```
"[HardCOdeText1 (HardCodeText2)].[HardCodeText3].[MatchString] between chamged1 and changed2"; or
"[MatchString] between changed1 and changed2";
```

I started to match "[MatchString] between" expression and I got stuck over there:
ANy help is appreciated.

Comment: Some parts of your example format strings look like they may be literal, and some parts are placeholders - for example in `between changeValue1 and changeValue2` I'm guessing you're looking for the literal words "between" and "and" so you need those literal terms in your regex, but *changeValue1* could be anything so you need a pattern there.  I also can't be sure if the `[` and `]` are as placeholders in your example or are literal square brackets.  Could you give an actual example of a real piece of text you want to match?

Comment: "[HardCOdeText1 (HardCodeText2)].[HardCodeText3].[MatchString] between changeValue1 and changeValue2" and [MatchString] between changeValue1 and changeValue2 are the strings I need to figure it out from.

Comment: Ok , How can I match the String that contains anything infront followed by "[MatchString] between" and any characters after that.

Comment: This kind of sounds like homework.

Answer (score 0):

[ and ] are reserved chars in regular expressions and you need to escape them.
Also, here is a really nice online regular expression tester that uses java regexp:

http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `"[MatchString] between"` as your pattern without escaping the `[]` brackets? The characters `[`, `]`, `.`, `(`, and `)` are all special characters in RegEx. If you want to refer to those as literal characters, you need to escape them in the pattern.

Your question is a little unclear. Maybe if you provided specific examples of a real input string you're using, and what you want the matches to look like?

I'd also check out [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for more information and tutorials, including info about and syntax for Java's implementation of RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

This will match both kinds of line examples that you give.

```
String inputLine;
String outputLine;

String regex1 = "(\\[MatchString\\] between )changeValue1 and";
String regex2 = "(\\[MatchString\\] between )[^ ]+ and";

do {
    inputLine = readTheInput();

    outputLine = inputLine.replaceFirst(regex1, "$1changed1 and");

    writeTheOutput(outputLine);
} while (thereIsStillInput());
```

The first `regex1` looks specifically for `changeValue1` while the second `regex2` looks for anything following "between" and preceding "and".

This should get you started.